# "Table already exists" error using Zumero sync in a Xamarin.Forms application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, zumero

When I run the app in the Xamarin Android player it works just fine, but when I run on a device I am getting the following error:

> Error 1 (sqlite): CREATE TABLE main."custScanned" ( z_rv INTEGER NULL UNIQUE REFERENCES "z$rv$1483152329"(z_rv) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED, "Id" integer primary key NOT NULL, "custNumber" text COLLATE NOCASE, "scannedDate" text COLLATE NOCASE ): table "custScanned" already exists
>       jni/../../../../..//build/android/core/jni/../../../../src/core/sg/sg_sqlite.c:304
>       jni/../../../../..//build/android/core/jni/../../../../src/core/client/zum_sync.c:558
>       jni/../../../../..//build/android/core/jni/../../../../src/core/client/zum_sync.c:2219
>       jni/../../../../..//build/android/core/jni/../../../../src/core/client/zum_sync.c:3889
>       jni/../../../../..//build/android/core/jni/../../../../src/core/client/zum_sync.c:4382
>       jni/../../../../..//build/android/core/jni/../../../../src/core/client/zum_sync.c:7703
>       jni/../../../../..//build/android/core/jni/../../../../src/core/client/zum_sync.c:7763
>       jni/../../../../..//build/android/core/jni/../../../../src/core/client/zum_sync.c:8871
>       jni/../../../../..//build/android/core/jni/../../../../src/core/client/zum_sync.c:9227

When I look at the LogCat on the device it says table `custScanned` already exists. I thought that was the point of syncing: to send data to the server and add data from the server to an existing table on the device.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it with help from Zumero support. I was creating the table at startup that is why the error was happening.

Answer (score 2):

While Zumero *does* want to sync your client tables with their server-side counterparts, it wants to *create* those tables itself on initial sync. So (as you discovered) you need to start with an empty SQLite database, or with a non-existent database — Zumero will create it for you on initial sync. Presumably the Android player did *not* have a pre-existing SQLite database, or at least did not have this table.

Zumero needs to create the housekeeping tables and other data, and get the client-side schema just right, in order to track history, merge changes, etc. with the server.  Without that information, there's no way to reconcile the structure and contents of a pre-existing database with the server-side data.